# After migration to Androidx, I have problem in 'Apache HTTP client' and 'camera'

Tags: android, android-camera, apache-httpclient-4.x, androidx

**Background:**

On Android Marshmallow, Google has completely removed the support of Apache HTTP client ([link here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#behavior-apache-http-client)) because it doesn't have good performance compared to the alternatives.

This might also be the cause for so many apps crashing on Android Marshmallow.

**The problem:**

I made a migration to `Androidx` and now `Apache httpclinet` not supported before `SDK version 23` (for example: `SDK 22,21,20,19,18,...`) and `Camera`  not supported after `SDK version 23` (for example: `SDK 23,24,...,28`).

**Iknow:**

Google allows you to still use this API, just not as a built in one, by adding this line to the gradle file:

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

When I tried it, it compiled fine, but when I tried using some of the classes that I know that are part of the old API (like "HttpClient" class), I see that it doesn't allow me to do so.

I know it's not recommended to use this solution, but we must have the app ready to work there at least temporarily, till we work 100% on all of the things that should change for Android Marshmallow, and we don't want surprises in the form of crashes.

**Here's a screenshot:**

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqc9G.jpg)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFlFO.jpg)

**The question:**

Why does it occur? Did I use it correctly?

Comment: what is your exact question?

Comment: I made a migration to `Androidx` and now `Apache httpclinet` not supported before SDK version 23 (for example: SDK 22,21,20,19,18,...) and `Camera` not supported after SDK version 23 (for example: SDK 23,24,...,28).